# pygame, python, MOUSEBUTTONDOWN one click

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame

SIZE = (440, 240)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
screen = pygame.Surface(SIZE)

class Platform:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fon = pygame.image.load('image/fon.png')
        self.blue = pygame.image.load('image/blue.png')

def make_level(level, platform):
    x = 0
    y = 0
    for i in range(len(level)):
        for j in range(len(level[i])):
            if level[i][j] == 1:
                screen.blit(platform.fon, (x,y))
            if level[i][j] == 2:
                screen.blit(platform.blue, (x,y))   
            x += 40
        y += 40
        x = 0

level = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0],
    [0,2,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,0]]

pl = Platform()

done = True
while done:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (mouseA,mouseB) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pix = 40
            a = int(mouseA/pix)
            b = int(mouseB/pix)
            print('b,a = ',level[b][a])
            if level[b][a] == 2:
                if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    (mouseX,mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    x = int(mouseX/pix)
                    y = int(mouseY/pix)
                    print('y,x = ', level[y][x])

    screen.fill((240,255,255))

    make_level(level, pl)

    window.blit(screen, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

надо переставить синие кружки из левой части в правую, но когда кликаю мышкой (MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) сразу же выполняется второе нажатие, как исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно к инициализации:

```
import pygame

SIZE = (440, 240)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(SIZE)
screen = pygame.Surface(SIZE)
```

Добавить:

```
clicked = False
```

Ну а `event` часть:

```
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (mouseA,mouseB) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pix = 40
            a = int(mouseA/pix)
            b = int(mouseB/pix)
            print('b,a = ',level[b][a])
            if level[b][a] == 2:
                if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    (mouseX,mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                    x = int(mouseX/pix)
                    y = int(mouseY/pix)
                    print('y,x = ', level[y][x])
```

Заменить на:

```
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = False
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            (mouseA,mouseB) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            pix = 40
            a = int(mouseA/pix)
            b = int(mouseB/pix)
            print('b,a = ',level[b][a])
            if level[b][a] == 2:
                if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if not clicked: # условие перемещения кругов
                        (mouseX,mouseY) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                        x = int(mouseX/pix)
                        y = int(mouseY/pix)
                        print('y,x = ', level[y][x])

                        clicked = True # клавиша мыши зажата
        if e.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            clicked = False
```